# How to scan for (erroneous) static IP configurations within DHCP server scope

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, dhcp, dhcp-server, ipv4

How can I scan for any statically configured IP addresses in use, within a Windows Server DHCP scope, of which the DHCP server is not aware?

I'm dealing with a network I inherited on which I found devices configured with a static IP *within* the DHCP server scope (without a matching configured reservation). DHCP leases for new (or clients roaming between VLAN's) within this scope sometimes take a long time to register. Also WiFi clients sometimes get configured with an [APIPA](https://wiki.wireshark.org/APIPA) address.

I want to rule out faulty static IP configurations within the IPV4 scope being the cause of this.

Answer (score 1):

Develop an IP Address Management strategy. Resource this project by getting people and IPAM tools to accurately track your address space.

The implementation is up to you. You know your environment, and we don't recommend products.

Yes, it will be very tedious to clean up by correlating traffic on the wire, DHCP, DNS, host static config, and an IPAM database. Impose discipline now to at least not make it worse.